# At PHP script MySQL query is returning NULL column

Tags: php, mysql, null

I have this sql query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM products p, products_description pd, products_to_categories c left 
     join  products_sex ps on (c.products_id = ps.products_id), 
     categories cc 
WHERE p.products_id = pd.products_id 
      and p.products_id = c.products_id 
      and cc.categories_id = c.categories_id 
      and p.products_status = 1 
      and p.products_price >= 15.8333333333 
      and p.products_price <= 40 
      and p.products_quantity > 0 
      and (ps.products_sex = "U" or ps.products_sex is null) 
      and (c.categories_id = 77 or cc.parent_id = 77) 
ORDER BY products_sort_order, p.products_date_added desc, pd.products_name ASC 
LIMIT 0, 40
```

If I execute it at MySQL client (command line or Navicat), I get this result:

```
products_id  |  dodavatelia_id  ...
2153         |  67              ...
```

But if I get products by PHP script (with mysql_query and mysql_fetch_assoc), I get:

```
array ( 
    'products_id' => NULL,  
    'dodavatelia_id' => '67', 
    ...
);
```

**Why am I getting the products_id NULL?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be because you are joining multiple tables that contains column with the same name, here `products_id` so you retrieve the value of the last column with this name that might be `NULL`.

You should put an alias for the column you want to retrieve :

```
SELECT p.products_id AS pPropId, p.* FROM products p, ...
```

Then in your PHP result you can access your column like this:

```
$result['pPropId']
```

More info on the SQL Alias functionality [here](http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql-aliases.htm).

EDIT: *Why does it work in the command line and not here?*

The SQL query works fine and will return **each** column of name `products_id`. The issue is that you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()` that returns an associative array based on your result. And you can't have multiple values for the same key in the array.

So what it might do internally is set `$result['products_id'] = p.products_id` but then it does the same for the next column with the same name erasing the previous value. You could use [mysql_fetch_row()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) which does not have this issue.

A good practice is to list the columns you really want to retrieve in your SELECT and not just `SELECT *`. Then it becomes logical that two columns with the same name need different aliases.

Comment: Thank you, this was it. But I don't understand, why it works in mysql command line and in PHP doesn't.

Comment: @yetty > Because the SQL query works fine. Check my updated answer